# Is it possible to output value if key is present in dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I've got a very small translation program and I am trying to figure out how to make the program output the corresponding value of a key, when the key has been input

This is what I've done so far, but I haven't been able to :

```
dict = {
    'down': 'ned',
    'up': 'op',
    'right': 'højre',
    'left': 'venstre',
    'diagonally': 'diagonalt',
}

for english, danish in list(dict.items()):
    print(f"{english.title()} means {danish} in Danish")

t_word = input("Type an English word you want translated:\n> ").lower()

if t_word in dict:
    print(f"The translation of {t_word} is:) # Can't figure out how to make it output the correct value

else:
    print("Sorry, I don't know that word.")
```

Ideally it would be possible to input an English word and check if that word is in the dictionary.
If it is, then the danish word should be output.

Hope you guys can help,
thanks :)

Comment: just do `dict[t_word]`

Answer (score 0):

```
print("The translation of {} is:{})".format(t_word, dict[t_word]
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.